# DBSCAN. Детектирование спам писем, при помощи нечеткого хеширования

Tags: python, cluster, sklearn, спам

Есть задача **детектирование спам писем, при помощи нечетких хешей**. Посмотрев кучу видео и прочитав не меньше статей, пришел к такому алгоритму:

1. Считываю [датасет](https://www.kaggle.com/code/owenpatrickfalculan/spam-email-classification/data), обрабатываю его, удаляю значения `None`, дубликаты.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ppdeep as pp

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

init_data = pd.read_csv('./spam2.csv')
data = init_data[['Label', 'Body']]
data.dropna(inplace=True)
data = data.rename(columns={'Body': 'message', 'Label': 'class'})
data = data.reindex(columns=['class', 'message'])
data = data.drop_duplicates(subset='message', keep="first")
```

2. Следующим этапом, я обрабатываю сами сообщения, насчет необходимости его я не уверен. Хотя если я не пропускаю этот этап, то появляется больше писем с одинаковым нечетким хешем, что логично.

```
import re
import html

from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer

# nltk.download('stopwords')
# nltk.download('punkt')

EMAIL_RE = re.compile("[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+")
URLS_RE = re.compile("http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:\%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+")
PUNCTUATION_RE = re.compile(r'[!"\#\$%\&\'\(\)\*\+,\-\./:;<=>\?@\[\\\]\^_`\{\|\}\~]')
NOT_LETTERS_OR_SPACE_RE = re.compile("[^A-Za-z ]")
REPEATING_LETTERS_RE = re.compile(r'([a-z])\1{2,}')

def prepare_message(message):
    # Convert to lower case
    text = message.lower()

    # Сonverts HTML codes into characters
    text = html.unescape(text)

    # Remove email
    text = re.sub(EMAIL_RE, ' ', text)

    # Remove urls
    text = re.sub(URLS_RE, ' ', text)

    # Remove all punctuation symbols
    text = re.sub(PUNCTUATION_RE, ' ', text)

    # Remove all except letters and space
    text = re.sub(NOT_LETTERS_OR_SPACE_RE, '', text)

    # Replace repeating letters
    text = re.sub(REPEATING_LETTERS_RE, r'\1', text)

    # Split by space and stemming with PorterStemmer
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    return ' '.join([ps.stem(word) for word in text.split()])

data['message'] = data['message'].apply(prepare_message)
```

После этого этого этапа, я получаю обработанные слова через пробел, без цифр и любых других символов.

3. Дальше, я добавляю столбец с нечетким хешем, каждого сообщения.

```
data['hash'] = data['message'].apply(pp.hash)
```

4. Далее я разделяю датасет, на обучающую и тестовую выборку (хотя, как я выяснил, в `DBSCAN` нельзя предсказывать новых значений, только добавлять в матрицу расстояний и по новой обучать, т.к. в `DBSCAN` нет статичных центров у кластеров, как например в `KMeans`)

```
x = data['hash']
y = data['class']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, stratify=y)
```

5. В следующем этапе, я рассчитываю матрицу расстояний между каждой парой сообщений.

```
import numba

@numba.jit(parallel=True, cache=True, fastmath=True)
def calc_distances(x_train, x):
    count = 0
    n = len(x_train)
    max_count = (n**2 - n) // 2
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            x[i,j] = pp.compare(x_train[i], x_train[j])
            x[j,i] = x[i,j]
            count += 1
            print(f"\r{count}/{max_count}", end='')
        
n = len(x_train)
distances = np.zeros((n, n))
calc_distances(list(x_train), distances)
np.fill_diagonal(distances, 100.0)
```

Тут я не придумал и не нашел, никаких идей по ускорения расчета матрицы, по этому сижу жду по 30 минут, если со всем датасетом то 70 :(

6. Заключительный этап. Кластеризация.

```
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.5, min_samples=2, min_metric='precomputed').fit(distances)

labels = db.labels_
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

print("Estimated number of clusters: %d" % n_clusters_)
print("Estimated number of noise points: %d" % n_noise_)
```

На этом этапе, у меня возникают проблемы. Как бы я не менял параметр `eps` и `min_samples`, на выходе я всегда получаю `1` кластер и `0` шума.

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем конкретно я ошибаюсь? В чем конкретно проблема? Может использовать, какой-нибудь другой алгоритм, кроме `DBSCAN`? Информации в интернете, правда очень мало, именно про детектирование спама, при помощи нечетких хешей.

Comment: Без данных довольно тяжело гадать. Я бы посмотрел, что у вас вообще в `distances` получилось, мож там константа. Ну и шаманство с `n_clusters_` какое-то неочевидное. Там точно всё нормально, тут не теряется один из классов?

Comment: @CrazyElf я прикрепил ссылку на датасет в 1 пункте. В `distances` все нормально, много нулей правда, но это связано с `pp.compare` и его реализацией. `n_clusters_` это кол-во кластеров, без учета `-1` т.к. это шум. Собственно первая часть это подсчет всех кластеров, а вторая часть это вычитание именно шума, если он есть. У меня, как я написал, шума не было, в один кластер входят все данные.